# aspx. need help and advices c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to develope simple aspx page there will be authorization box if username and password boxes and one button. I want to make when password and username will be correct start downloading rar which is on ftp.
Password and usernames are in sql table 
Ftp have password, how to authorization on ftp 
So my problem is that i dont know how to start downloading. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FTPWebRequest (FTP client assemblies) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx